# Are the cshtml files just copied when published?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it OK let the designers to download the cshtml files (MVC 4) from a published site and modify the files for layout/styling? (And later the developers' cshtml files can be replaced by the ones from designers)

If I remember correctly, the old version of Asp.Net webform may change the `.aspx` files after published. Will `.cshtml` files be untouched after published.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cshtml files means C Sharp HyperText Markup Language, e.i its html with C Sharp Code (Razor Syntax).

Offcourse your designers can download the cshtml file(mind it you cannot download cshtml files from a published website) edit it and reupload it. but make sure they dont tinker with the razor syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Yes cshtml files can be modified to change the layout/styling on a published site.